# Using angular ngrx store effects to query data by id

Tags: angular, ngrx, apollo-client, ngrx-effects

I am using ngrx 6 and angular 6, my code looks as follows:

1. effects.ts

   ```
   import * as fromProjectMemberActions from '../project-member/project-member.actions';
   import * as fromProjectMemberGraphQL from '../../members/members.graphql';

   @Effect({dispatch: false})
   loadProjectMember$ = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(fromProjectMemberActions.ProjectMemberActionTypes.GetProjectMembers),
   tap(
     action => {
       this.apollo.watchQuery({
         query: fromProjectMemberGraphQL.GET_ALL_PROJECT_MEMBERS,
         variables: { 
           projectID : // Project ID is needed
         }
       }).valueChanges.subscribe((response: any) => {
           console.log(response)
           this.store.dispatch(
             new fromProjectMemberActions.UpsertProjectMembers({
               projectMembers: response.data.findAllProjectMember
             })
           )
           this.store.dispatch(
                 new fromProjectMemberActions.DoneLoadingProjectMembers()
             )
       })
     }
   )
   );
   ```
2. project-member.actions.ts

   ```
   export class GetProjectMembers implements Action {
     readonly type = ProjectMemberActionTypes.GetProjectMembers;
   }
   export class UpsertProjectMembers implements Action {
     readonly type = ProjectMemberActionTypes.UpsertProjectMembers;
       constructor(public payload: { projectMembers: ProjectMember[] }) {}
     }
   ```
3. members.graphql.ts

   ```
   import gql from 'graphql-tag';

    export const GET_ALL_PROJECT_MEMBERS = gql`
    query getAllProjectMembers($projectID: Long!) {
       findAllProjectMembers(projectId: $projectID) {
         id
         memberId
         memberType
      }
    }
   `;
   ```
4. The given graphql API is seen as follows on graphql playground

   ```
   query{
     findAllProjectMembers(projectId: projectID) {
       id
       memberId
       memberType
     }
   }
   ```

   If you replace projectID above with a number eg: 2 it will query data successfully
5. The url where the Project ID to be used on number 1 is passed through the following URL

   ```
   http://localhost/project-manager/view-project/2/members
   ```

I need help to extract that project ID above and use it in effects file to query a list of members

Comment: where you are dispatching the action ofType(fromProjectMemberActions.ProjectMemberActionTypes.GetProjectMembers) in the component. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say.

// update project-member.actions.ts

```
export class GetProjectMembers implements Action {
  readonly type = ProjectMemberActionTypes.GetProjectMembers;
  constructor(public payload: { projectId: number }) {}
}
```

// and update effect

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
loadProjectMember$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(fromProjectMemberActions.ProjectMemberActionTypes.GetProjectMembers),
map((action: any) => action.payload),
tap(
  payload => {
    this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: fromProjectMemberGraphQL.GET_ALL_PROJECT_MEMBERS,
      variables: { 
        projectID : payload.projectId
      }
    }).valueChanges.subscribe((response: any) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.store.dispatch(
          new fromProjectMemberActions.UpsertProjectMembers({
            projectMembers: response.data.findAllProjectMember
          })
        )
        this.store.dispatch(
              new fromProjectMemberActions.DoneLoadingProjectMembers()
          )
    })
  }
)
);
```

// may be in the component or where you dispatching action Pass projectId

```
subscribe to router {
  this.store.dispatch(new GetProjectMembers({ projectId })
}
```